# R column with a strange value

Tags: r, data-analysis

In one column of my dataset the assignment of a record to a phase is listed. Phase I (I), Phase II (I), Phase III (I). Each dataset has an assignment, in the evaluation there seems to be another value that I can't locate. This gives an error in the evaluation. I can't find the dataset in question. I would either exclude it, make it an NA value, or assign it to a phase if necessary. Do you have a tip on how I can proceed, apparently there is no record with the weird "blank" value either?

```
> summary(May_Filter_2$Phase)
      I II III 
  0 424 850 975
```

Best, Roman

Comment: You have blank as a factor level "". Drop unused factor levels, see linked post. Try: `summary(droplevels(May_Filter_2$Phase))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have you dataset, so I don't really know if this function could help to fix your problem. You can use this simple code to substitute na value with 0 (or with whatever you want).

```
May_Filter_2[is.na(May_Filter_2)] <- 0
```